# wordpress wp e-commerce update to 3.8 version broke the shop

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, upgrade, fatal-error

I did Update of the WP e-Commerce plugin in my Wordpress 3.6.1 (by clicking Update in Installed plugins in my WordPress).

I then got a red box at the top saying:

```
Your WP e-Commerce data needs to be updated. You've upgraded from a previous version of the WP e-Commerce plugin, and your store needs updating.
You should update your database for your store to continue working.
```

I have 36 products currently. Had to refresh page several times to get most of my products updated and display them on the website (as they disappeared on update).
Normally on a refresh I got a few more products updated so the number (example below) was rising eg. displayed 6/36 then 8/36 and so on.

The problem is it's got stuck on the last product - it says now:

```
Update WP e-Commerce

Updating Categories...

Updating Variations...

Updating Products ...

Estimated time left:Under a minute
35/36
```

I already refreshed page several times and still getting stuck on the same number - 35.

The error message I get on the final refresh is:

```
<div class="eta">Estimated time left:Under a minute</div>
<br>
<b>Fatal error</b>
: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
<b>/home/eduedupl/public_html/martinezguitar/wp-includes/class-wp-image-editor-imagick.php</b>
on line
<b>318</b>
```

Not sure what I can do with it?
When I go to Products page I still have a red message saying I need to update the plugin and the database to continue working. But on Installed plugins page it looks like the plugin is fine and doesn't shout for the upgrade anymore.And there is no Delete option, only Deactivate...

My products are messed up on the website so their pages just display all products in the shop the way the main shop page does...

If I add a new category or product their link just go to Page Not Found...

So there is something wrong with the database
And I don't even have an option to delete the plugin... and start from scratch. Big bugger

Anyone can help please?

Thanks

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-e-commerce/

Answer (score 0):

In the future before running plugin, core, or theme updates make sure to test them on a development server first for compatibility.

Increase the maximum execution time in your php.ini, cross your fingers and hope it completes.

http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php

Comment: @user1611620 who is your host? Most hosting companies allow you to have a php.ini within your root folder which will override the main servers file. Ask their tech support

Comment: I managed to uninstall the plugin and installed it again. All works fine now.

Comment: It didn't work - checkout and updaing data in the cms were broken for example so I just removed wp e-commerce and used another shop plugin instead

Comment: @user1611620 ok well WooCommerce in my opinion is the best eCommerce plugin for WordPress. If you need more help contact me http://bit.ly/UHR2WS